# How to check if a number is not larger than double in C

Tags: c, double

I need to make sure all input is correct in a program i'm writing. I have a function that suppose to make sure the number the user enters is not larger than double. My function doesn't work, and I don't understand why. Here is my function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <limits.h>

int smallerThanDouble (double user_num)
{
    if(user_num>DBL_MAX)
        return FALSE;
    return TRUE;
}
```

any idea why?

thanx...

Comment: Well, `DBL_MAX` is supposed to be _the maximum_ value a `double` can hold. How can you expect any `double` be _greater_ than it?

Comment: This should work. How did you tested it? Try for example `smallerThanDouble(2*DBL_MAX)`. A number larger than DBL_MAX would be represented as _infinity_.

Comment: Maybe you should show how you get the input and how you call the function

Comment: The solution is to use [`strtod()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtod.3.html) with proper error checking when converting a string to a double. The `scanf()` family of functions does not check for overflow.